# Cómo devolver multiples resultados de una dt table usando una Clase

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

La idea es que de una consulta que me devuelve X cantidad de registros, me devuelva un xml con cierta estructura. el problema es que uso un foreach para cada registro pero no funciona.

Método que expone el servicio:

```
[WebMethod]
public PolContainer PolizaXRiesgo(string polAliasRiesgo)
    {
//SQL Query using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ...
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {               
        pc.Poliza = new PolizasRes();
        pc.Poliza.Id = 7541;
        pc.Poliza.NumPoliza = "FA56779057";

        pc.Poliza = new PolizasRes();
        pc.Poliza.Id = 9327;
        pc.Poliza.NumPoliza = "FA70049057";
        }
    }
```

//Clase Raiz

```
public class PolContainer
{
    public PolizasRes Poliza { get; set; }
}
```

//Sub Elemento

```
public class PolizasRes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NumPoliza { get; set; }
}
```

Por Soap me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
<PolizaXRiesgoResult>
   <Poliza>
      <Id>9327</Id>
      <NumPoliza>FA70049057</NumPoliza>
   </Poliza>
</PolizaXRiesgoResult>
```

Necesito que me devuelva así:

```
<PolizaXRiesgoResult>
   <Poliza1>
     <Id>7541</Id>
     <NumPoliza>FA56779057</NumPoliza>
   </Poliza1>
   <Poliza2>
      <Id>9327</Id>
      <NumPoliza>FA70049057</NumPoliza>
   </Poliza2>
    (.....)
 </PolizaXRiesgoResult>
```

Probé creando para la clase PolContainer varias instancias de la misma con un número, es decir lo siguiente:

```
public class PolContainer
{
    public PolizasRes Poliza1 { get; set; }
    public PolizasRes Poliza2 { get; set; }
    public PolizasRes Poliza3 { get; set; }
}
```

Pero esto serviría si supiera que los resultados siempre son 3 registros, pero como ya sabrán, puede ser 1 o 10 registros, o aun más.

¿Entonces cómo creo una nueva instancia de la clase PolizasRes por cada registro en la DataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que modificar tu clase raíz para que quede del siguiente modo:

```
public class PolContainer
{
     public List<PolizasRes> Poliza { get; set; } //Indicamos que vamos a regresar una colección de PolizasRes
}
```

Luego, al regresar los resultados tu código debe quedar lo siguiente:

```
[WebMethod]
public PolContainer PolizaXRiesgo(string polAliasRiesgo)
{
   //SQL Query using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
    ...
    pc.Poliza = new List<PolizasRes>(); //Una instancia de la colección para contener los resultados.
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {               
        PolizasRes pol = new PolizasRes(); //Nueva instancia
        pol.Id = 7541; //Recupero valores y los coloco en la instancia
        pol.NumPoliza = "FA56779057";  //Aunque debo recolectar la información de cada DataRow
        pc.Poliza.Add(pol); //Una vez recuperada la información, la agrego a la lista.
    }
    //Luego retorno los datos (deber ser la instancia pc)...
}
```

Te va a regresar algo como lo siguiente:

```
<PolizaXRiesgoResult>
  <Poliza>
    <Id>7541</Id>
  <NumPoliza>FA56779057</NumPoliza>
</Poliza>
<Poliza>
   <Id>9327</Id>
   <NumPoliza>FA70049057</NumPoliza>
 </Poliza>
(.....)
</PolizaXRiesgoResult>
```

Como verás no hay un Polizax en el regreso, todos los elementos de la respuesta  regresan con el mismo nombre.

Comment: Si señor así es, pero... me queda la duda para PolizaX, no debería tener un Id de Nodo diferente para cada uno?, al deserializarlo no habría inconvenientes?

Comment: No, no vas a tener problema en la serialización/deserialización. Todos los elementos de la lista se diferenciarán uno de otro por los datos. En tu caso, el valor del elemento Id en el XML o de la propiedad Id de la instancia de tu lista.